# Writeable Samba subfolder inside read-only folder

Tags: samba

I want to share home folder as read-only with everyone while making its temp sub-folder writable. I tried:

```
[Home]                 
path = /home/bamw      
browsable =yes         
writable = no          
guest ok = yes         
read only = yes        
force user = bamw      

[Temp]                 
path = /home/bamw/temp 
browsable =yes         
writable = yes         
guest ok = yes         
read only = no         
force user = bamw
```

But it looks like read-only permissions of /home/bamw override writable access to temp. What's the correct way to do it without creating dedicated Samba users?

Comment: are filesystem permissions ok? i would say nobody.nogroup and 777 for writeable folder. trivial to say that such a configuration should be used in a very restricted environment.

Comment: chmoding temp to 777 did not help

Comment: chmoding + chown?

Comment: yep: drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup 4.0K 20-02-10 10:48:46 temp

Comment: Result of `ls -ld / /home /home/bamw /home/bamw/temp` please. (In your question.)

Comment: @roaima
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 10 10:48 /home/bamw/temp

Comment: Jack, (1) please put that [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/566736/edit), not in the comments, (2) please check all the directories that I've asked, not just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up - the suggestion of realpclaudio in the comments solves the issue, i.e.

```
chmod 777 /home/bamw/temp
chown nobody:nogroup /home/bamw/temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `create mask = 777` to RW share.

You can also reset permissions and ownership to `bamw`

Obviously you can't write to `Temp` if you enter in `Home` first, but if you go straight to `Temp` it will work.